# sql order by best matched results from one specific where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Hi I'm using sql server 2008 and have a big stored procedure which has multiple where clauses. Within one of those clause I have the following:

```
WHERE clause1
    AND (clause2)
    AND (clause3)
    AND (clause4)
    AND (clause5)
    AND (clause6) 
    AND ( COL1 LIKE '%' + @VARIABLE + '%' OR COL2 LIKE '%' + @VARIABLE + '%')
```

I'm looking to show results in an order, whereby I get the results where BOTH matched in clause 7 first, followed by if one matched. Is this possible? I've tried a few things but nothing has worked so far. E.g:

```
SELECT 
BLAH BLAH
FROM MULTIPLE TABLE JOINS
WHERE clause1
    AND (clause2)
    AND (clause3)
    AND (clause4)
    AND (clause5)
    AND (clause6) 
    AND ( COL1 LIKE '%' + @VARIABLE + '%' OR COL2 LIKE '%' + @VARIABLE + '%')
ORDER BY
(CASE WHEN COL1 LIKE '%'+ @VARIABLE + '%' AND COL2 LIKE '%' + @VARIABLE + '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
```

and

```
SELECT BLAH BLAH, (case when COL1 LIKE '%'+ @VARIABLE + '%' then 1 else 0 end) +
      (case when COL2 LIKE '%'+ @VARIABLE + '%' then 1 else 0 end) as [priority]
FROM MULTIPLE TABLE JOINS
WHERE clause1
    AND (clause2)
    AND (clause3)
    AND (clause4)
    AND (clause5)
    AND (clause6) 
    AND ( COL1 LIKE '%' + @VARIABLE + '%' OR COL2 LIKE '%' + @VARIABLE + '%')
ORDER BY [Priority]
```

And a few more but nothing has worked...

Comment: probably best to remove clause1 -> clause6 in your samples as they aren't actually relevant to what you're asking, as you're simply interested in `COL1 Like.. COL2 Like..` part and if one of both match

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is ordering based on your condition:

```
CASE WHEN COL1 LIKE '%'+ @VARIABLE + '%' AND COL2 LIKE '%' + @VARIABLE + '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

But it's redundant with your `WHERE` clause:

```
COL1 LIKE '%'+ @VARIABLE + '%' AND COL2 LIKE '%' + @VARIABLE + '%'
```

Add the `CASE` statement from your `ORDER BY` to your `SELECT` and you'll see it's `1` for every row, so the `ORDER BY` is working as it should, it just has no impact since all records are being ordered by `1`, you need to alter the `ORDER BY` criteria, if you give additional detail about how you want it ordered someone can surely help.